# Tcl: Multiple conditionals inside the if statement

Tags: tcl

Just trying to do some basic check in a script... to produce an error if `$argc` is not either 1 or 2.

I tried:

```
if { ( $argc != 1 ) || ( $argc != 2 ) } {
        puts "ERROR: \$argc should be either 1 or 2.\n"; exit 1
}
```

and

```
if { ( $argc != 1 || $argc != 2 ) } {
        puts "ERROR: \$argc should be either 1 or 2.\n"; exit 1
}
```

etc.

but couldn't make it work using any of the parenthesis/brace combinations.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Google "De Morgan's Theorem". English is unfortunately very lax when it comes to logic and I see this problem mostly when people try to convert the concept of "neither". If you think REALLY REALLY HARD about this (or if you had studied either logic or digital design) you would have realised that "neither 1 nor 2" actually means "not 1 and not 2" instead of "not 1 or not 2". The phrase "not 1 or not 2" by definition is ALWAYS TRUE because 1 is not 2 therefore the "or not 2" part is true and 2 is not 1 therefore the "not 1" part is true. What you want is "not (1 or 2)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is basic logic.

Your example won't work because 2 is not equal to 1 so the first test is true.

To negate an OR conjunction, you negate each test and change the OR to an AND.
You want this state:

```
if { ( $argc == 1 ) || ( $argc == 2 ) } {
  puts "ok"
} else {
  puts "ng"
}
```

So use:

```
if { ( $argc != 1 ) && ( $argc != 2 ) } {
  # i.e. if $argc is either anything other than a 1 or a 2...
  puts "ERROR: \$argc should be either 1 or 2.\n"; exit 1
}
```

Comment: Alternatively `!  ($argc == 1 || $argc == 2)` which is equivalent. The transformation between `! (A||B)` to `!A && !B` is known as De Morgan's Theorem (basically `! (A||B) === !A && !B`)

Answer (score 5):

Another way:

```
if {$argc ni {1 2}} { ... }
```

That is: if the value of argc is *not in* the list containing 1 and 2, ...

The `ni` operator requires Tcl 8.5 or later.

Documentation:
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[ni (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm)